# May i know how to solve the errors i have in my code?

Tags: c++

Question :May i know how to solve the errors i have in my code ,view all and delete the waffle that the customer want and doesn't want without using any linked list?

> C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp   In function 'void orderForm()':
>   321 17  C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] 'extraFillings' was not declared in this scope
>   332 41  C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] invalid operands of types 'const char [29]' and '' to binary 'operator/'
>   335 19  C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] 'extraToppings' was not declared in this scope
>   341 15  C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] 'taxInvoice' was not declared in this scope
>   355 1   C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] a function-definition is not allowed here before '{' token
>   569 11  C:\Users\Arianna\Documents\LABC++\Lab2\ASSIGNMENT DSA SEM2 2.cpp    [Error] expected '}' at end of input

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char choice,options;
    char *tmp,*tmp2;
    int sentinel=0;
    double priceSoft1=10.00,priceCrispy1=12.00,priceSoft2=14.00,priceCrispy2=16.00,priceSoft3=12.00,priceCrispy3=14.00;
    double payment,total;
    double TotalAmt1,TotalAmt2,TotalAmt3,TotalAmt4,TotalAmt5,TotalAmt6;
    double Fillings=1.20,Toppings=1.50;
    double TotalAmount1,TotalAmount2,TotalAmount3,TotalAmount4,TotalAmount5,TotalAmount6;
    char wMenu[100];
    int listOption,orderForm;
    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6;
}

class waffle 
{
    private:
        struct cashier
        {
            char name [30]; //Name up to 30 letters
            int idNum; //Id Number in Integer
            cashier *next;//Pointer to the next node
        };
        cashier *start_ptr;//Start pointer (root)

    public:

        waffleShop()
                    {
                        start_ptr=NULL;
                    }//Add constructor and initialize start pointer to NULL

            int cashierList();
            void add_new_acc();
            void displayList();
            void delete_start_ptr();
            void delete_end_node();

};


int waffle::cashierList()
{
    char choice,options;

    int listOption=0;

    cout<<"Please choose the option from the list";
    cout<<"<<1>>Add node at the end of the list"<<endl;
    cout<<"<<2>>Display List"<<endl;
    cout<<"<<3>>Delete first"<<endl;
    cout<<"<<4>>Delete last"<<endl;
    cout<<"<<5>>Sign Out"<<endl;
    cin>>listOption;

    switch(listOption)
    {
        case 1:
            add_new_acc();
            break;
        case 2:
            displayList();
            break;
        case 3:
            delete_start_ptr();
            break;
        case 4:
            delete_end_node();
            break;
        case 5:
            cout<<"Would you like to sign out?";
            cout<<" \n Press [Y] for Yes, and [N] for No.\n\n\tEnter Choice : ";
            cin >>choice;

        if  ((choice !='N')&&(choice !='n'))
            {

                return cashierList();
            }
        else
            {

                cout<<"You have already sign out from the system";
                system("cls");
            }

        break;
    }
        return 0;
}

void waffle::add_new_acc()
{

    cashier *tmp,*tmp2;//temporary pointers

    tmp=new cashier;
    //Reserve space for the new node to fill in data
    cout<<"Create New Account"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter your name:"<<endl;
    cin>>tmp->name;
    cout<<"To create your Cashier ID"<<endl;
    cout<<"Please enter last 4 digit of your Id: "<<endl;
    cin>>tmp->idNum;

    tmp->next=NULL;

    if(start_ptr==NULL)

        start_ptr=tmp;

    else
    {
        tmp2=start_ptr;//The list is not empty since it is not NULL

        while(tmp2->next!=NULL)
        tmp2=tmp2->next;//move to next link 
        tmp2->next=tmp;

    }

        cashierList();
}

void waffle::displayList()
{
    char wMenu[100];

    cashier *tmp;
    tmp=start_ptr;

    while(tmp)
    {
        cout<<"Cashier Name:"<<tmp->name<<endl;
        cout<<"Cashier Id:"<<tmp->idNum<<endl;

        tmp=tmp->next;

    }

    main();
}

void waffle::delete_start_ptr()
{
    cashier *tmp;

    tmp=start_ptr;
    start_ptr=start_ptr->next;
    delete tmp;

    cashierList();
}

void waffle::delete_end_node()
{
    cashier *tmp1,*tmp2;

    if(start_ptr==NULL)

    cout<<"You're not in the list"<<endl;

    else
    {
        tmp1=start_ptr;
        if(tmp1->next==NULL)
        {
            cout<<"You are a New User!!"<<endl;
            delete tmp1;
            start_ptr=NULL;

        }
        else
        {
            while(tmp1->next !=NULL)
            {
                tmp2=tmp1;
                tmp1=tmp1->next;

            }

            delete tmp1;
            tmp2->next=NULL;
        }
    }

    cashierList();
}

void wMenu()
{
    char options;

    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout<<"WAFFLE TYPE ! CRISPY(RM) ! SOFT(RM) ! EXTRA CHARGE(RM) !";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout<<"1)American  ! 12.00      ! 10.00    ! - RM1.20 for additional filling";
    cout<<"2)Belgium   ! 16.00      ! 14.00    ! - RM1.50 additional topping";
    cout<<"3)Rolled    ! 14.00      ! 12.00    !/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t/t";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------";
    cout<<"Options:";
    cout<<"\nFilling-choc,butter,kaya,ice cream,strawberry,blueberry";
    cout<<"\nTopping(except for Rolled Waffle)";
    cout<<"a)ice cream-vanila,chocolate or mix flavour";
    cout<<"b)fruits-banana or strawberry";
    cout<<"----------------------------------------------------------------------";

    cout<<"Would you like proceed your order?"<<endl;
    cin>>options;

    cout<<" \n Press [Y] for Yes, and [N] for No.\n\n\tEnter Options : ";
    if  ((options !='N')&&(options !='n'))
            {

                 main();
            }
        else
            {
                cout<<"Next Customer please ";
                return wMenu();

            }
}
void orderForm()
{
    int order, choiceA,choiceB;
    int num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6;
    double AmountSale1,AmountSale2,AmountSale3,AmountSale4,AmountSale5,AmountSale6;
    double priceSoft1=10.00,priceCrispy1=12.00,priceSoft2=14.00,priceCrispy2=16.00,priceSoft3=12.00,priceCrispy3=14.00;


    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(1)Soft American Waffle RM10.00   ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(2)Crispy American Waffle RM12.00 ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(3)Soft Belgium Waffle RM14.00    ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(4)Crispy Belgium Waffle RM16.00  ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(5)Soft Rolled Waffle RM12.00     ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(6)Crispy Rolled Waffle RM14.00   ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";

    while(order!=0)
    {
    do
    {   
    cout<<"\nFrom the waffle menu , what would you like : ";
    cin>>order;
    }
    while(1<order<5);
    switch(order)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"How many soft American waffle would you like:";
            cin>>num1;

            AmountSale1=priceSoft1*num1;

            break;

        case 2:
            cout<<"How many crispy American waffle would you like:";
            cin>>num2;

            AmountSale2=priceCrispy1*num2;

            break;

        case 3:
            cout<<"How many soft Belgium waffle would you like: ";
            cin>>num3;

            AmountSale3=priceSoft2*num3;

            break;

        case 4:
            cout<<"How many crispy Belgium waffle would you like: ";
            cin>>num4;  

            AmountSale4=priceCrispy2*num4;

            break;

        case 5:
            cout<<"How many soft Rolled waffle would you like :";
            cin>>num5;

            AmountSale5=priceSoft3*num5;

            break;

        case 6:
            cout<<"How many crispy Rolled waffle would you like :";
            cin>>num6;

            AmountSale6=priceCrispy3*num6;

            break;

        default:cout<<"Please choose a valid order from the menu\n";

    }


    cout<<" Do you want to add fillings? ";
    cout<<" \n Press [Y] for Yes, and [N] for No.\n\n\tEnter Choice : ";
    cin >> choiceA;

     if ((choiceA ='Y')&&(choiceA !='N')&&(choiceA ='y')&&(choiceA !='n'))
    {

        extraFillings();

    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"Would you like to add Topings?";
        cout<<" \n Press [Y] for Yes, and [N] for No.\n\n\tEnter Choice : ";
        cin>>choiceB;

        if((choiceB ='Y')&&(choiceB !='N')&&(choiceB ='y')&&(choiceB !='n'))
        {
            cout<<"Topping(except ROLLED WAFFLE"/endl;
            if(order!=5&&order!=6) 
            {
                extraToppings();
            }

            else
            {

            taxInvoice();


            }

        }


    }

}


void extraFillings()
{
    int typeofFillings,

    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(1)Soft American Waffle RM10.00   ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(2)Crispy American Waffle RM12.00 ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(3)Soft Belgium Waffle RM14.00    ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(4)Crispy Belgium Waffle RM16.00  ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(5)Soft Rolled Waffle RM12.00     ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(6)Crispy Rolled Waffle RM14.00   ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";

    cout<<"Waffle Added with Filings RM1.20 will be charged"


    cout<<"Remark:    ";
    cin>>typeofFillings;

switch(order)
{
    case 1:
        TotalAmt1=AmountSale1+Fillings;

        break;

    case 2:
        TotalAmt2=AmountSale2+Fillings;

        break;  

    case 3:
        TotalAmt3=AmountSale3+Fillings;

        break;

    case 4:
        TotalAmt4=AmountSale4+Fillings;

        break;

    case 5:
        TotalAmt5=AmountSale5+Fillings;

        break;

    case 6:
        TotalAmt6=AmountSale6+Fillings;

        break;

    default:cout<<"Please choose a valid order from the menu\n";
}

    extraTopings(void);
}

void extraTopings()
{
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(1)Soft American Waffle RM10.00   ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(2)Crispy American Waffle RM12.00 ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(3)Soft Belgium Waffle RM14.00    ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(4)Crispy Belgium Waffle RM16.00  ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";

    cout<<"*****TOPPINGS OF ROLLED WAFFLE IS INVALID*****";
    cout<<"Remark:    ";
    cin>>typeofTopings;

    switch(order)
{
    case 1:
        TotalAmount1=AmountSale1+Toppings;

        break;

    case 2:
        TotalAmount2=AmountSale2+Toppings;

        break;  

    case 3:
        TotalAmount3=AmountSale3+Toppings;

        break;

    case 4:
        TotalAmount4=AmountSale4+Toppings;

        break;

    default:cout<<"Please choose a valid order from the menu\n";
}

    taxInvoice();
}

void taxInvoice();
{
    int  ans,select;
    double payment;
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(1)     Normal Waffle             ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(2)     Waffle with Fillings      ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";
    cout<<"(3)     Waffle with Toppings      ";
    cout<<"----------------------------------";


    cout<<" You have ordered:\n\n";
    cout<<"Select the selection  ";
    cin>>select;
    if(select==1)
    {
     cout<<"NORMAL"/endl;

     cout<<" ITEM\t\t\t\tQUANTITY\tUNIT PRICE\tAMOUNT OF SALE\n";

     cout<<" Soft American Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num1<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft1<<"\tRM   "<<AmountofSale1<<"\n";
     cout<<" Crispy American Waffle:\t\t"<<num2<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy1<<"\tRM "<<AmountofSale2<<"\n";
     cout<<" Soft Belgium Waffle:\t"     <<num3<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft2<<"\tRM   "<<AmountofSale3<<"\n";
     cout<<" Crispy Belgium Waffle:\t\t" <<num4<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy2<<"\tRM "<<AmountofSale4<<"\n";
     cout<<" Soft Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t"  <<num5<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft3<<"\tRM   "<<AmountofSale5<<"\n";
     cout<<" Crispy Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num6<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy3<<"\tRM "<<AmountofSale6<<"\n";

    total=0;
    total=total+AmountofSale1+AmountofSale2+AmountofSale3+AmountofSale4+AmountofSale5+AmountofSale6;

    }
    else
    {
        if(select==2)
        {


            cout<<"With Fillings"/endl;

            cout<<" ITEM\t\t\t\tQUANTITY\tUNIT PRICE\tAMOUNT OF SALE\n";

            cout<<" Soft American Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num1<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft1<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmt1<<"\n";
            cout<<" Crispy American Waffle:\t\t"<<num2<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy1<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmt2<<"\n";
            cout<<" Soft Belgium Waffle:\t"     <<num3<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft2<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmt3<<"\n";
            cout<<" Crispy Belgium Waffle:\t\t" <<num4<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy2<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmt4<<"\n";
            cout<<" Soft Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t"  <<num5<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft3<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmt5<<"\n";
            cout<<" Crispy Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num6<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy3<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmt6<<"\n";

            total=0;
            total=total+TotalAmt1+TotalAmt2+TotalAmt3+TotalAmt4+TotalAmt5+TotalAmt6;

        }
        else
        {
            if(select==3)
            {
                cout<<"With Toppings"/endl;

                cout<<" Soft American Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num1<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft1<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmount1<<"\n";
                cout<<" Crispy American Waffle:\t\t"<<num2<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy1<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmount2<<"\n";
                cout<<" Soft Belgium Waffle:\t     "<<num3<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft2<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmount3<<"\n";
                cout<<" Crispy Belgium Waffle:\t\t "<<num4<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy2<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmount4<<"\n";
                cout<<" Soft Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t  "<<num5<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceSoft3<<"\tRM   "<<TotalAmount5<<"\n";
                cout<<" Crispy Rolled Waffle:\t\t\t"<<num6<<"\t\tRM   "<<priceCrispy3<<"\tRM "<<TotalAmount6<<"\n";

                total=0;
                total=total+TotalAmount1+TotalAmount2+TotalAmount3+TotalAmount4+TotalAmount5+TotalAmount6;

            }

        }
    }
    cout<<"\t\t\t\t\t\tThat would be:  RM "<<total<<"\n";

        cout<<"Order Again[0]no[1]yes"
        cin<<ans;
        if(ans==0)
        {
            if(payment<total)
            {
                cout<<"Insufficient Money";
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"\n\tEnter Received Cash : ";
                cin >> payment;

                if(payment>total)
                {
                    change=payment-total;
                    cout<<"\tYour change is:"<<change<<"\n\n\n\n\t\t"
                }
            }


                do
                {
                cout<<" New transaction [0] no [1] yes : ";
                cin >> ans;
                } while ((ans != 0)&&(ans != 1));
        }
                system("cls\n\n\n\t\t");
                system("PAUSE");

        return 0;

}
```

Comment: -1 because.... 1) You tagged your c++ problem as C#, 2) you're asking stack overflow to do your homework for you, 3) You can't properly format a question and I don't feel like getting a headache trying to decipher your hodge-podge of text.

Comment: Please refer to SO [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AdamPlocher Sorry i have just learned to code and 1st time using stack over flow to ask my problem solving it because the problem is I'm trying to improve myself as i'm a beginner for coding.

Answer (score 0):

The error "function X was not declared in this scope" is because you call a function that is declared after the one calling it in the file. At compile time there is no way for the compiler to know what it is.
For example : orderForm calls extraFillings it is not defined yet as it is defined later in the file.
You need to create a header file containing the prototypes of your functions and linked it to your project or you need to make sure that the function you are calling are declared before the caller.